# proper root path in php without using document_root

Tags: php

I have used `$_server 'document_root'` in my project where it has run well on my localhost but I got an issue with it when I uploaded it to the remote server. I am getting this error when I accessed this file

```
Warning: include(D:\Hosting\4391629\htmlforevision/php/tab1.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\4391629\html\othersites\forevision\forevision\home\index.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'D:\Hosting\4391629\htmlforevision/php/tab1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\Hosting\4391629\html\othersites\forevision\forevision\home\index.php on line 2
```

Please help me out of this. Is there any thing to do with the server to get permissions for `$_server['document_root']` or should use any other syntax. I have already used `$_server['http_host']`, `__dir__`, etc. Please help me out of this...

Answer (score 0):

Are you not just missing the / after your document root. eg,

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/forevision/php/tab1.php';
```

Comment: not exactly sure where your document root is. but looking at the error it definitely looks like there should be a / in the middle of htmlforevision